# Why is the integer 0 when I create an object and get that integer value using getters and setters?

Tags: java, getter-setter

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Test2 t2 = new Test2();
        t2.test();
        System.out.println(t2.getNum());
        
    }
}

public class Test2 {

    private int num;

    public void test() {
        Test2 t = new Test2();
        t.setNum(3);
        System.out.println(t.getNum());
    }
    
    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    public void setNum(int bruh) {
        this.num = bruh;
    }
    
}
```

Whenever I create an object of `Test2` and set the value of `num` using `t2.test()`, It prints out on the console as 0 when using `t2.getNum()`. Why does it return a value of 0? And how do I fix it so it actually gets the value I want? Class `Test` and `Test2` are separate files as a side note.

Comment: In `test()` you are creating an object that is _not_ the instance `t2` so when you call that method then `t.num` will be set but `t2.num` won't be changed. You might want to revisit what an instance method or field means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void test() {
    Test2 t = new Test2();
    t.setNum(3);
    System.out.println(t.getNum());
}
```

You create a new instance of `Test2` locally in the method, which has no impact on `this` instance.

```
public void test() {
    setNum(3);
}
```

would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

`t2` and `t` or 2 different objects.

When you call `t2.test()`, you create a new object `t` and you set the attribute num of the `t` object, not `t2`. So when you call `t2.getNum()`, the `num` attribute of `t2` keep is default value which is zero for integer in Java.